# IPTABLES nat to LXD Containers

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, scripting

I created the following temporary rule that I enable occasionally but I would like to remove it without the need of restarting the machine.

Can someone provide me the command?

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eno1 -p TCP -d 149.202.80.48/32 --dport 2020 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.167.147.211:2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo iptables -t nat -D <whatever you did had after -I>`

(D stands for delete)